# How to make a save as draft module in django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on some modules that email all data that should save in the database
with the attached file. I don't know how to save them as drafts in Django, Help me to solve this problem. I am new to Django.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you have already done, please add [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just create a normal save and then create a function to prevent everyone except yourself from viewing the post.

Comment: okay got it but what should i do to select from draft and automatically fill into those fields?

Comment: i don't know about that